# How to get list of table used in any particular query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, netezza

I need help in getting list of all table used in any particular query in SQL Server whether its part of join or any subquery.

I am expecting output as below.

Lets say query is->
"select A.*, B.col1, B.col2 from table1 A inner join table2 B on A.abc=b.abc"

Expected output is list of table used in above query. which is table1, table2

Is there any way i can get the tables used for any random query?

## -----------------------------------------------------------

Thankyou Everyone - I get it worked for SQL Server. I am looking for same thing for Netezza also.

Is there any equivalent for sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set in Netezza which can provide same results?

Comment: Not propery a list, but with query plan you can see how the query was built with Sql Server engine

Comment: If you can wrap the query into an SP or view (for example) and compile it, you can check the dependencies in `sys.sql_dependencies`. Won't work with dynamic SQL of course.

Comment: Partial answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45737413/5070879 only when columns is returned as resultset.

Comment: There are just too many ways to get this wrong. If your code uses views, functions or dynamic sql you are going to miss tables. Not to mention aliases.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your query into a stored-procedure (e.g. sp_Dummy), then you can get the dependencies with

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     o.name 
    ,o.type_desc 
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(QUOTENAME(N'dbo') + N'.' +  QUOTENAME(N'sp_Dummy'), 'OBJECT') AS dm 

INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o 
    ON o.object_id = dm.referenced_id 

INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS sch 
    ON sch.schema_id = o.schema_id
```

Here a procedure shell

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[sp_Dummy]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Dummy] AS' 
END
GO


-- =======================================================
-- Author:      XXXX
-- Create date: 31.10.2019
-- Description: Dummy procedure to infer dependencies
-- =======================================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Dummy]
     @in_object_type AS varchar(2) 
    ,@in_object_uid AS uniqueidentifier 
    ,@in_report_date AS datetime2 
    -- your query's parameters go here...
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- your query goes here
END


GO
```

This won't get dynamic sql, though - but I think that's as good as it can get.

You can extract all paramters with:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(sql, @"\@\w+")
    .Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
```