# Get a list of tables accessed by a SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have many hundred SQL select statements stored in the database table in a `nvarchar` column.

For each select statement, I need to find out what tables they read from. I need to do this programmatically (e.g. with T-SQL) and store the list of accessed tables in a database table.

I started doing this by calling the stored procedure `sp_describe_first_result_set`.  It works only partially.

For example:

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set  
  @tsql = 'SELECT 
               a.code, b.customer_name
           FROM table_a a 
           INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.code = b.code
           WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM table_c c
                             WHERE a.code = c.code)',
  @params = null, 
  @browse_information_mode = 2
```

This returns `source_table` values `table_a` and `table_b` but not `table_c`.

I need the list of accessed tables.

Any ideas on how I would achieve this?

Comment: Makes sense - since that system stored procedure describes what makes up the **result set** - and no column from `table_c` is included in the result set ....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of tables used in an SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692344/list-of-tables-used-in-an-sql-query)

Comment: If you are able to capture xml query plans (via trace) then the xml has each table which is used in query. Take a look at using set showplan_xml on in a query window then look at the results of executing a query. If you save the resulting file as xml you should easily be able to find the tables accessed.

Comment: I should have said using extended events rather than trace

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about creating a temporary view, then use the built in dependency functions to get the referenced tables and then drop the views, rinse and repeat, replace the @sql with your own statements:

```
declare @tsql varchar(max) = 'SELECT 
               a.code, b.customer_name
           FROM table_a a 
           INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.code = b.code
           WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM table_c c
                             WHERE a.code = c.code)'

exec ('create view vwtmp as ' + @tsql)

select OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id) referencing_entity,
        o.[type_desc] as referenced_entity_type, referenced_entity_name
from sys.sql_expression_dependencies d
inner join sys.objects o
    on d.referenced_id = o.[object_id]
where OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id) = 'vwtmp'

exec ('drop view vwtmp')
```

This is what my test returns:

```
referencing_entity  referenced_entity_type  referenced_entity_name
------------------  ----------------------  ----------------------
vwtmp               USER_TABLE              table_a
vwtmp               USER_TABLE              table_b
vwtmp               USER_TABLE              table_c
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @tsql NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @tsql = 'SELECT 
           a.code, b.customer_name
       FROM table_a a 
       INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.code = b.code
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                         FROM table_c c
                         WHERE a.code = c.code)'

---------------------------------
DECLARE @localTable TABLE (source_table  varchar(100))
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(50) = '', @found int = 0
DECLARE tables_cursor CURSOR FOR   
    select value from string_split(@tsql, ' ')
    WHERE len(value) > 0
OPEN tables_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @string 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
    IF @found = 1
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @localTable VALUES(@string)
        set @found = 0
    END
    IF @string IN('JOIN','FROM')
        set @found = 1
    FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @string 
END
CLOSE tables_cursor
DEALLOCATE tables_cursor

select * from @localTable

----output
source_table
table_a
table_b
table_c
```