# OrderBy based on list of fields and Asc / Desc rules

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following `List` with `OrderBy` parameters:

```
List<String> fields = new List<String> { "+created", "-approved", "+author" }
```

This would result in the following Linq query:

```
IQueryable<Post> posts = _context.posts.AsQueryable();

posts = posts
   .OrderBy(x => x.Created)
   .ThenByDescending(x => x.Approved);
   .ThenBy(x => x.Author.Name);
```

So basically the rules are:

1. Use the first item in the `OrderBy` and the others in `ThenBy`.
2. Use descending when the field starts with `-` and ascending when with `+`.

My idea would be to have something like:

```
OrderExpression expression = posts
  .Add(x => x.Created, "created")
  .Add(x => x.Approved, "approved")
  .Add(x => x.Author.Name, "author");
```

So the expression associates the post properties / child properties to each key in fields. Then it would be applied as follows:

```
posts = posts.OrderBy(expression, fields);
```

So the `OrderBy` extension would go through each item in the OrderExpression and apply the rules (1) and (2) to build the query:

```
posts = posts
   .OrderBy(x => x.Created)
   .ThenByDescending(x => x.Approved);
   .ThenBy(x => x.Author.Name);
```

How can this be done?

Comment: So the set of possible fields along with the corresponding property selectors are predefined?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to keep it simple. So basically the OrderExpressions defines which field is associated with which property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is the joint effort of [@YacoubMassad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2290059) and me. Take a look at the separate answers for details. The following code works perfectly and even translates to SQL without issues (I checked the query with the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579092/tsql-get-last-queries-ran) on a 2008 R2), so all the sorting is done on the server (or wherever you data is, it works with simple lists too of course).

**Example usage:**

```
OrderExpression<Post> expression = new OrderExpression<Post>()
    .Add(x => x.Created, "created")
    .Add(x => x.Approved, "approved")
    .Add(x => x.Author.Name, "author");

IQueryable<Post> posts = _context.posts.AsQueryable();

posts = posts.OrderBy(expression, "+created", "-approved", "+author");
// OR
posts = posts.OrderBy(expression, new string[]{"+created", "-approved", "+author"});
// OR
posts = posts.OrderBy(expression, fields.ToArray[]);
```

[And of course a live demo on dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ww7XC9)

**Code:**

```
public class OrderExpressions<T>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression> _mappings = 
        new Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression>();

    public OrderExpressions<T> Add<TKey>(Expression<Func<T, TKey>> expression, string keyword)
    {
        _mappings.Add(keyword, expression);
        return this;
    }

    public LambdaExpression this[string keyword]
    {
        get { return _mappings[keyword]; }
    }
}

public static class KeywordSearchExtender
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo OrderbyMethod;
    private static readonly MethodInfo OrderbyDescendingMethod;

    private static readonly MethodInfo ThenByMethod;
    private static readonly MethodInfo ThenByDescendingMethod;

    //Here we use reflection to get references to the open generic methods for
    //the 4 Queryable methods that we need
    static KeywordSearchExtender()
    {
        OrderbyMethod = typeof(Queryable)
            .GetMethods()
            .First(x => x.Name == "OrderBy" &&
                x.GetParameters()
                    .Select(y => y.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
                    .SequenceEqual(new[] { typeof(IQueryable<>), typeof(Expression<>) }));

        OrderbyDescendingMethod = typeof(Queryable)
            .GetMethods()
            .First(x => x.Name == "OrderByDescending" &&
                x.GetParameters()
                    .Select(y => y.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
                    .SequenceEqual(new[] { typeof(IQueryable<>), typeof(Expression<>) }));

        ThenByMethod = typeof(Queryable)
            .GetMethods()
            .First(x => x.Name == "ThenBy" &&
                x.GetParameters()
                    .Select(y => y.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
                    .SequenceEqual(new[] { typeof(IOrderedQueryable<>), typeof(Expression<>) }));

        ThenByDescendingMethod = typeof(Queryable)
            .GetMethods()
            .First(x => x.Name == "ThenByDescending" &&
                x.GetParameters()
                    .Select(y => y.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
                    .SequenceEqual(new[] { typeof(IOrderedQueryable<>), typeof(Expression<>) }));
    }

    //This method can invoke OrderBy or the other methods without
    //getting as input the expression return value type
    private static IQueryable<T> InvokeQueryableMethod<T>(
        MethodInfo methodinfo,
        IQueryable<T> queryable,
        LambdaExpression expression)
    {
        var generic_order_by =
            methodinfo.MakeGenericMethod(
                typeof(T),
                expression.ReturnType);

        return (IQueryable<T>)generic_order_by.Invoke(
            null,
            new object[] { queryable, expression });
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> data, 
        OrderExpressions<T> mapper, params string[] arguments)
    {
        if (arguments.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException(@"You need at least one argument!", "arguments");

        List<SortArgument> sorting = arguments.Select(a => new SortArgument(a)).ToList();

        IQueryable<T> result = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < sorting.Count; i++)
        {
            SortArgument sort = sorting[i];
            LambdaExpression lambda = mapper[sort.Keyword];

            if (i == 0)
                result = InvokeQueryableMethod(sort.Ascending ? 
                    OrderbyMethod : OrderbyDescendingMethod, data, lambda);
            else
                result = InvokeQueryableMethod(sort.Ascending ? 
                    ThenByMethod : ThenByDescendingMethod, result, lambda);
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class SortArgument
{
    public SortArgument()
    { }

    public SortArgument(string term)
    {
        if (term.StartsWith("-"))
        {
            Ascending = false;
            Keyword = term.Substring(1);
        }
        else if (term.StartsWith("+"))
        {
            Ascending = true;
            Keyword = term.Substring(1);
        }
        else
        {
            Ascending = true;
            Keyword = term;
        }
    }

    public string Keyword { get; set; }
    public bool Ascending { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works great. I just marked this one as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This following class will help you do it. You can find the explanation of code inline.

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Order<T>(
        IQueryable<T> queryable,
        List<string> fields,
        //We pass LambdaExpression because the selector property type can be anything
        Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression> expressions)
    {
        //Start with input queryable
        IQueryable<T> result = queryable;

        //Loop through fields
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.Count; i++)
        {
            bool ascending = fields[i][0] == '+';
            string field = fields[i].Substring(1);

            LambdaExpression expression = expressions[field];

            MethodInfo method = null;

            //Based on sort order and field index, determine which method to invoke
            if (ascending && i == 0)
                method = OrderbyMethod;
            else if (ascending && i > 0)
                method = ThenByMethod;
            else if (!ascending && i == 0)
                method = OrderbyDescendingMethod;
            else
                method = ThenByDescendingMethod;

            //Invoke appropriate method
            result = InvokeQueryableMethod( method, result, expression);
        }

        return result;
    }

    //This method can invoke OrderBy or the other methods without
    //getting as input the expression return value type
    private static IQueryable<T> InvokeQueryableMethod<T>(
        MethodInfo methodinfo,
        IQueryable<T> queryable,
        LambdaExpression expression)
    {
        var generic_order_by =
            methodinfo.MakeGenericMethod(
                typeof(T),
                expression.ReturnType);

        return (IQueryable<T>)generic_order_by.Invoke(
            null,
            new object[] { queryable, expression });
    }

    private static readonly MethodInfo OrderbyMethod;
    private static readonly MethodInfo OrderbyDescendingMethod;

    private static readonly MethodInfo ThenByMethod;
    private static readonly MethodInfo ThenByDescendingMethod;

    //Here we use reflection to get references to the open generic methods for
    //the 4 Queryable methods that we need
    static MyClass()
    {
        OrderbyMethod = typeof(Queryable)
            .GetMethods()
            .First(x => x.Name == "OrderBy" &&
                        x.GetParameters()
                            .Select(y => y.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
                            .SequenceEqual(new[] { typeof(IQueryable<>), typeof(Expression<>) }));

        OrderbyDescendingMethod = typeof(Queryable)
            .GetMethods()
            .First(x => x.Name == "OrderByDescending" &&
                        x.GetParameters()
                            .Select(y => y.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
                            .SequenceEqual(new[] { typeof(IQueryable<>), typeof(Expression<>) }));

        ThenByMethod = typeof(Queryable)
            .GetMethods()
            .First(x => x.Name == "ThenBy" &&
                        x.GetParameters()
                            .Select(y => y.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
                            .SequenceEqual(new[] { typeof(IOrderedQueryable<>), typeof(Expression<>) }));

        ThenByDescendingMethod = typeof(Queryable)
            .GetMethods()
            .First(x => x.Name == "ThenByDescending" &&
                        x.GetParameters()
                            .Select(y => y.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
                            .SequenceEqual(new[] { typeof(IOrderedQueryable<>), typeof(Expression<>) }));
    }

}
```

Here is an example usage:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + ", " + Age;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person {Name = "yacoub", Age = 30},
            new Person {Name = "yacoub", Age = 32},
            new Person {Name = "adam", Age = 30},
            new Person {Name = "adam", Age = 33},
        };

        var query = MyClass.Order(
            persons.AsQueryable(),
            new List<string> { "+Name", "-Age" },
            new Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression>
            {
                {"Name", (Expression<Func<Person, string>>) (x => x.Name)},
                {"Age", (Expression<Func<Person, int>>) (x => x.Age)}
            });

        var result = query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've taken the libery to *borrow* some of your code for a joint answer (yours works better and mine is easier to use). I hope you don't mind.

Comment: That is fine @ManfredRadlwimmer

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Changed Code to closely match your syntax

*This code sorts on the client, but works with all `IEnumerables`. If you absolutely need to sort on the database, take a look at Yacoub's `static MyClass()` to see how he solved this problem.*

The example below is based on the information you provided, you might need to adjust it a bit.

```
public class DemoClass
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public bool Approved { get; set; }
    public Person Author { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Since your example contains `author` which actually resolves to `Author.Name`, you need to create some sort of mapping for your keywords (Like you did with your `OrderExpression` class).

```
public class OrderExpressions<T>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string,Func<T,object>> _mappings = 
        new Dictionary<string,Func<T, object>>();

    public OrderExpressions<T> Add(Func<T, object> expression, string keyword)
    {
        _mappings.Add(keyword, expression);
        return this;
    }

    public Func<T, object> this[string keyword]
    {
        get { return _mappings[keyword]; }
    }
}
```

Which could be used like this:

```
OrderExpressions<DemoClass> expressions = new OrderExpressions<DemoClass>()
    .Add(x => x.Created, "created")
    .Add(x => x.Approved, "approved")
    .Add(x => x.Author.Name, "author");
```

You can pass those functions / lambda expressions, directly to Linq and add the next comparison one after another. Start with `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescrending`, that will give you your first `IOrderedEnumerable` and then add all remaining arguments with `ThenBy` or `ThenByDescending`.

```
public static class KeywordSearchExtender
{
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data, 
        OrderExpressions<T> mapper, params string[] arguments)
    {
        if (arguments.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException(@"You need at least one argument!", "arguments");

        List<SortArgument> sorting = arguments.Select(a => new SortArgument(a)).ToList();

        IOrderedEnumerable<T> result = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < sorting.Count; i++)
        {
            SortArgument sort = sorting[i];
            Func<T, object> lambda = mapper[sort.Keyword];

            if (i == 0)
                result = sorting[i].Ascending ? 
                    data.OrderBy(lambda) : 
                    data.OrderByDescending(lambda);
            else
                result = sorting[i].Ascending ? 
                    result.ThenBy(lambda) : 
                    result.ThenByDescending(lambda);
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class SortArgument
{
    public SortArgument()
    { }

    public SortArgument(string term)
    {
        if (term.StartsWith("-"))
        {
            Ascending = false;
            Keyword = term.Substring(1);
        }
        else if (term.StartsWith("+"))
        {
            Ascending = true;
            Keyword = term.Substring(1);
        }
        else
        {
            Ascending = true;
            Keyword = term;
        }
    }

    public string Keyword { get; set; }
    public bool Ascending { get; set; }
}
```

All together it be used like this:

```
var data = WhateverYouDoToGetYourData();

var expressions = new OrderExpressions<DemoClass>()
            .Add(x => x.Created, "created")
            .Add(x => x.Approved, "approved")
            .Add(x =>x.Author.Name, "author");

var result = data.OrderBy(expressions, "+created", "-approved", "+author");
// OR
var result = data.OrderBy(expressions, fields);
```

You can find my [proof-of-concept on dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NtZrAq).

Comment: It seems to me that this solution works with `IEnumerable<T>`, and not `IQueryable<T>`. I think that OP wants a solution that generates a query that can be executed against the database.

Comment: `IQueryable` inherits from `IEnumerable` so it will work with both. If not, it's a simple change to the extension method.

Comment: You would need to use `Expression<Func<T,TKey>>` instead of `Func<T,TKey>`. Also note that you will might face problems if you use `Expression<Func<T,object>>` instead of `Expression<Func<T,TKey>>`.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Good idea, If it's an `Expression<>` it shoud convertible to SQL - I'll do that. Hard to get rid of `TKey`

Comment: I am interested to see if it now works against a database. I remember once that using `Expression<Func<T, object>>` instead of `Expression<Func<T, TRealPropertyValue>>` didn't work for me.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't, Linq can't cast Sql datatypes to `object`

Comment: This is why I have the `InvokeQueryableMethod` method in my answer and why I used reflection to call the `OrderBy` and other methods instead of calling them directly.